# No module named my_unique_try_Xymostech error on django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I started a project and an application in it:

```
django-admin.py startproject blog
cd blog
python manage.py startapp my_unique_try_Xymostech
```

in the file `blog/url.py` in `urlpatterns`:

```
(r'^my_unique_try_Xymostech/$', 'blog.my_unique_try_Xymostech.views.my_unique_try_Xymostech'),
```

in the file `my_unique_try_Xymostech/views.py`:

```
def my_unique_try_Xymostech(request):
    print "bla bla"
```

but when running the server (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`) I get the error:

```
No module named my_unique_try_Xymostech
```

- What had I missed while doing the procedure ?

Comment: `try` is a keyword in python, I don't think you can have a function called `try`.

Comment: I tried other names, `sdayhadsioasdiadsjkl` isn't a keyword :)

Comment: I don't think that's your (main) problem, but in your `try/views.py`, you can't have a function named `try`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the url.py is already in the app, you mentioned blog/url.py, I don't think you need the `blog` in `'blog.my_unique_try_Xymostech.views.my_unique_try_Xymostech'`

Just try

```
(r'^my_unique_try_Xymostech/$', 'my_unique_try_Xymostech.views.my_unique_try_Xymostech'),
```

I didn't verify by creating a django app just now, but that may be it.

I usually add my django app to the python path so something like this wouldn't be a problem if you do that, I think.